# Replicating a Julia example

Tags: julia

I am trying to learn Julia and I read [this article](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/10/the-unreasonable-effectiveness-of-the-julia-programming-language/3/) about the quick success of Julia. In the last page of the article the author works a small example showing the benefits of multiple dispatch. They define a custom class `Spect` and define a `plot()` function for it. Then for an object `sqw` of type `Spect` they can call `plot(sqw)` without having to edit the original plot function. Moreover, this definition also affects similar plotting functions so that you can also call `scatter(sqw)` without problems. My issue is that author does not show the code, so I do not understand how can you achieve this. I am specially interested in the fact that just defining `plot()` for this new class is enough to also call other functions like `scatter()` without defining them for the new class.

Can someone write a small example of this like that of the article so that I can understand how all of this is achieved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: note that this is a cross post of https://discourse.julialang.org/t/replicating-a-julia-example/78646

Comment: It's the other way around, I posted there after posting here.

Comment: It's still a cross post, regardless of posting order. It's not a huge deal, but for the next time, just add a small note that it's been posted on two sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross posting my answer from Discourse:
It’s a shame the article doesn’t link to the code. Here’s my rough reproduction attempt. My version uses the dct and idct so I’m not getting the nice harmonics, but I think it shows the ideas pretty well.

```
using RecipesBase, FFTW
struct Spect
    points :: AbstractRange
    weights :: Vector{Float64}
end
function Spect(f::Function, min, max, n)
    points = range(min, max, n)
    Spect(points, dct(f.(points)))
end

@recipe function f(S::Spect)
    S.points, idct(S.weights)
end
```

These definitions are enough for

```
using Plots
squarewave(x) = iseven(floor(x)) ? 1.0 : 0.0
sqw = Spect(squarewave, 0, 5, 20);

plot(sqw)
scatter(sqw)
```

[image: plot]

and

[image: scatter]

Comment: It was fun to learn how recipes work (I've never used them before, and figured it out by looking at a few packages that use them). I'm hoping someone edits my post to make the plot be wavier. It should be pretty easy, but it's not entirely obvious to me how to do it.